# Grep a textfile with (find generated) files, but ignore paths

Tags: files, find, grep, paths, ignore

I receive a huge textfile generated with find.

The contents of the generated textfile are a file-referenes with full path, i.e.:

```
//server/dir1/dir1foobar.ext
//server/dir1/dir2/dir1bar.ext
//server/dir1/dir2/dir1.ext
//server/dir3/dir4/dir4.ext
//server/dir5/dir6/dir7/dir1foo.ext
//server/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir2.ext
//server/dir3/dir4/dir5/dir6/dir3.ext
```

(filenames and paths are kinda random, so I can't start always at position n from the begining or the end of a line)

I need to `grep` this textfile for a specific pattern, write the results (which needs to be a complete line for a match) into a new (sorted with `sort`) file, but also need to ignore any match which is not a filename.

So, with my example-lines above, I have a search pattern "dir1" and the result must be a new file containing those lines:

```
//server/dir1/dir1foobar.ext
//server/dir1/dir2/dir1bar.ext
//server/dir1/dir2/dir1.ext
//server/dir5/dir6/dir7/dir1foo.ext
```

My attempts with `sort -f -u $textfile | grep -i $pattern > $newfile` were not successful, because grep has a match too when the directory contains the pattern, which will result in a "false" match for `//server/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir2.ext`.

I read in `grep` manual that regex is possible with option `-G` but could'nt fiddle out any way to grep only in the filenames part of a line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try grepping like this:

```
grep -i 'dir1[^/]*$'
```

Which means it will only accept the match if it matches `dir1`, and that match is not followed by any `/` until the end of the line.